# QTiles Plugin maximum store support, intensive computing time?

Tags: qgis, tiles, memory

We try to compute 187 000 tiles with QGIS plugin QTiles in zoom level 18 (around 3000 square kilometres). There are 25 layers in there (mainly polylines and polygones). It took much longer than usual to compute these (it's not done yet). The first 18 000 tiles took over 12h to compute.

I know all of this depends on computer adjustments, capacity, etc. and it depends on the number of shapes. My concrete questions are:

- Is there a maximum memory/store support on the part of the plugin?
- Are there other QGIS plugins you can recommend for this task (with these - parameters)?